# Automatic Web Scraping with Name Specification

Tags: ios, r, csv, web-scraping, automation

So I am interested in webscraping a specific website at the end of each day, and export a .csv file with a unique name. I have actually managed to create a very simple script for scraping the data onto a data.frame and exporting it. Though I am not sure how to best go about making this process automated. I am using a MacBook Pro 2016, in case that matters.

I have determined (after a quick Google search) that there are two things I can do; either create a plist file that executes a command or use the Automator app in the computer. I have saved a tutorial on YouTube for creating a plist file, but I am quite afraid of creating one, because I am not very good with computers and I do not want to create a serious bug.

As I mentioned before, I want my computer to run an R script at a specific time everyday (during the work week), and I want this date reflected in the name of the CSV file that would be exported. For example, when the R script runs on Monday 04/10/2017, I want the exported CSV file to be data.04.10.2017. It would be fine to just have all the exported .csv's dumped into one folder (the same directory), so long as the name is standardized in this way.

My script does not incorporate a command for creating a unique name for the csv file for each day of the week. On a separate script I tried feebly to create a "for" or "repeat" structure to manually create each day of the year, but to no avail. And even if I did, I would not know how to combine this "date scrip" with my main web-scraping script.

In conclusion, I would like to ask the following:

1. What is the safest way to automate a task, for a beginner like me? [to run an R script daily]. Is my fear of creating a plist file warranted, given my inexperience?
2. How do I improve my script so that it would generate a unique name for each csv that is exported each day? For example, `data.04.10.2017`, `data.04.11.2017`...
3. Is this something best done by R or another program?

For reference, here is my working script:

```
library(xml2)
library(rvest)

URL = url('https:website)

raw.data = read_html(URL) %>% html_nodes('thenode') %>% html_text()

#this tells R to fetch the data from the website
#you can find the node you want by going to the webpage, right click the page and click "view page source"
#nodes are denoted like this <NODE>INFORMATION</NODE>
#use the selector gadget Google Chrome extension to choose your web page element!

#remove weird lines of data; standardize it. 
#raw.data = raw.data[c(-157:-160, -171, -172, -183, -184, -205, -206)]

#Now it should follow this format: 
    #(space)
    #v1
    #v2
    #v3
    #v4
    #(space)

    #now I want to remove the (space) throughout the whole dataframe. 

deletions = seq(1,280, 5)
raw.data = raw.data[-deletions]
matrix1 = matrix(data = raw.data, nrow = 4)
View(matrix1)

#at this point, the data is sort of in reverse form
#we want the entire first row to be the first column instead

v1 = matrix1[1,]
v2 = matrix1[2,]
v3 = matrix1[3,]
v4 = matrix1[4,]

#here, I am acquiring the data row by row to create the dataframe
#we have each row separated. We will now reconstruct the data frame correctly

final.data.frame = data.frame(v1,v2,v3,v4)
View(final.data.frame)

#this is the final data frame.


write.csv(final.data.frame, "C:/directory/file.csv")

#to export the data in excel (or csv form)
#how do I best incorporate unique names at this point of the script?
```

Comment: The usual way to do (1) would be cron or another command line job scheduler. For (2), something like `paste0('data.', Sys.Date(), '.csv')`.

Comment: @alistaire, thanks! So I added this line to my script: `data.name = paste('market',Sys.Date(),'csv', sep = ".")`. I am currently trying to find a way to use the write.csv command where I can use a created vector when I type out the name of the directory in one of the arguments. It seems that I have to type out the name of the csv file manually, since it is in quotes. Is there a way to append the vector string to the write.csv(file = , "directory/file.csv"), where I can put the vector in place of the "file.csv"?

Comment: Sure, just `file = paste0('directory/data.', Sys.Date(), '.csv')` or whatever variant thereof you like.